# How to get js file array to node js server?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have one Javascript file linked to HTML and that js file is calculating an array on clicking submit button in Html and I want to get that data to node js file on post route without displaying it in HTML page. How should I do that?

Comment: Hi Gourav. You can send a HTTP request with ajax from the front-end to the node server.

Answer (score 0):

Your nodeJS program is running on a server, which could just be your computer if you are using localhost, which means that it is in not connected to your HTML page. Therefore, you need to send the data from your js file via fetch request. In your nodeJS file, you need a route for receiving that data, which you create using express.

```
const express = require("express");
const {json} = require("body-parser");

const app = express(); 

app.post("/submitData", (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body;
    console.log(data);
    res.status(200).json({"Message": "Data posted", data});
})

app.listen(3000,() => {
    console.log("Server running on port 3000");
})
```

Now, in your javascript file, you need a fetch request.

```
fetch(http://localhost:3000/submitData, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then(response => {
    return response.json();
}).then(data => {
    console.log(data)
})
```

This should do the trick. I would also suggest you download Postman, which is great for testing APIs and trying out http requests

Comment: There is a function in js file which is calculating data, should I place the above code in that function or globally?

Comment: ```Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client``` I am getting this error

Comment: put the fetch request in the function for calculation data.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to point out, after doing:

```
const app = express();
```

you should put:

```
app.use(json());
```

I apologise for the mistake, it should remove the error you mentioned in the comment.